# GCM user notification - getting different notification_key when registering from device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to send GCM notifications to all my devices running the same app without using a backend server.

I have an application that generates a user notification key on the client (phone).  I was expecting that I would get back the same user notification key on every device that uses the same Google account.

Note that I am talking about the notification_key not the registration_id (I understand the registration_id is device specific).

However, I don't get the same notification_key on all devices. I am passing in the same notification_key_name and using the same account to generate the id_token but I get back a different notification_key on each device.

To make matters worse, if my app version changes and I have to add the new registration id for the device, I get back a new notification key.

Do I have some basic misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work?

Request:

```
{
 "operation":"add",
 "notification_key":"APA...cxU",
 "notification_key_name":"<user>",
 "id_token":"ey...",
 "registration_ids":["APA...wQ"]
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "notification_key":"APA...-QQ"
}
```

The above is real exchange showing that the trailing bytes of the notification_key I received are different than the trailing bytes of the notification_key that was submitted in the request.

Android API Level 19.
Eclipse ADT on Windows

Comment: registration_ids are uniques. So when app is uninstall and reinstall, id is different. Actually, id id unique by Phone AND app installation !

Comment: I am talking about the a notification_key not a registration_id. I understand the the registration_id is unique to each device. I thought the whole purpose of the notification_key was to send messages to multiple devices.

Comment: What headers are you sending?  I'm trying to generate a notification key on the client side, and I think I've implemented everything correctly, but I get a 401 Unauthorized response.